# Every first-order logic formula without quantifiers can be written in disjunctive normal form.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, disjunctive-normal-form

I'm trying to prove the fact that every first-order logic formula without quantifiers  can be written in disjunctive normal form (Disjunction of conjuctions) of atomic formulas and their negations; however, I'm having problem in the inductive step:

> Let $\varphi = (\neg \psi)$, by induction hypothesis $\psi = \bigvee\limits_{i=1}^{m} \bigwedge\limits_{j=1}^{n} \sigma_{ij} $ where $\sigma_{ij}$ is an atomic formula, then using De Morgan:
>   $$
> \varphi = \bigwedge\limits_{i=1}^{m} \bigvee\limits_{j=1}^{n} (\neg\sigma_{ij})
> $$

How do I get the normal disjunctive form?

Comment: You say: first-order ... Are you working with quantifiers?  If not, do you mean a propositional logic formula?

Comment: it is now fixed

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm just now trying to see how the indexes will change in the general case.

Comment: Hmm, not pretty ... Assuming you have the same number of disjuncts (say $n$) per conjunct, and assuming you have $m$ conjuncts, then doing the distribution gives you $n^m$ disjuncts, each consisting of $m$ literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always distribute the $\land$'s over the $\lor$'s.

For example,

$$(P \lor Q)\land (R \lor S) \Leftrightarrow (P \land R) \lor (P \land S) \lor (Q \land R) \lor (Q \land S)$$